# compile clipper dos application

Tags: dos, clipper

I have an old point of system program written in clipper. I have successfully decompiled the program in RESCUE5. The decompiler has written the source files to .udf. I have made the necessary changes to the .udf files and I would to recompile the program now. What is the best way to do this.

Sample of the .udf file

```
/* ------ Rescue5 1.11 (c) APTware 1993,94 ------
Name: ACC_CN
Params: None.
Return: Logical
Example: ACC_CN()
..........................................................................
*/

FUNCTION ACC_CN()

  LOCAL cStr := SPACE(1)
  LOCAL cStr1 := SPACE(5)
  LOCAL nNum, nNum1, nNum2, nNum3, nNum4, nNum5, nNum6, _Def, nNum7 := ;
     0, nNum8 := 1
  LOCAL nNum9 := 0, nNum10 := 0, nNum11 := 0

  IF MEMVAR->T_CODE[1] = "     "

  SCROLL(21, 3, 21, 36)
  SETPOS(21, 3)
  DEVPOS(21, 3)
  DEVOUT(PADC("No details entered ... Hit a key", 35))
  SET(17, "OFF")
  __WAIT("")
  SET(17, "ON")
  RETURN .F.

 ENDIF

 GET_REM()
 SCROLL(21, 3, 21, 36)
 SETPOS(21, 3)
 DEVPOS(21, 5)
 DEVOUT("Accept details and print ?")
 SETPOSBS()
 AADD(GETLIST, __GET({|_bDef|IF(_bDef == NIL, cStr, cStr := _bDef)}, ;
     "conf", NIL, NIL, NIL))
 READMODAL(GETLIST)
 MEMVAR->GETLIST := {}
```

Comment: You need something like [xHabrour](http://www.xharbour.org/) - whatever is better supported these days.

Comment: Thanks I am busy downloading it will give a go and let you know

Comment: There is also the original [Harbour](https://harbour.github.io/) and some other clones may still have a community behind them.

Comment: I ran xharbour and one of the arguments is .prg file for command line execution. Can i just rename my source files from .udf to .prg

Comment: If this is what they are.

Comment: I have included a sample of the source in the question

Comment: Looks like PRG.  Not sure if x/Harbour supports this low level stuff. Good luck.

Comment: As @PM77-1 pointed looks like PRG file, have you tried to save as PRG and use clipper compiler?

Comment: Why is this tagged c?

Comment: good point removed the tag

Answer (score -1):

If you want to compile things in CLIPPER, use .PRG files in plain CLIPPER language. You will get databases in DBF format. It might be helpful to find an application that works with SQL databases. That is a very easy way to import DBF files to SQL.

In addition, you can import the DBF files to Microsoft Access.

If you look around you may find Nantucket Clipper 5.2e. This is very stable and friendly.

You might find a book by someone named Straley or similar.

Comment: hey, it might not be a good idea to expose your personal data such as phone number on stackoverflow